# How to change name key or attribute in json

Tags: php, arrays, json

Please help me

how do I change the key name or manifest_description attribute in a json array, I have used foreach, but the data hasn't changed, what should I do...

```
 <?php
 $json = json_decode($response);
 $data['Status'] = success;
 $riwayat1 =  $json->rrr->result->manifest;
 $track = array();
 foreach($riwayat1 as $e) {  
 $riwayat =  $json->rajaongkir->result->manifest;          
 $track[] = array(
 'No Telp' => $riwayat
 );
 }
$tester = array(
//'riwayat' => $riwayat,
'riwayat' => $track
 );           
 $data['data'] = $tester;
  $data = json_encode($data);
 echo $data;
```

preview

```
{
"Status": "success",
"data": {
  "riwayat": [
       {
    "manifest_code": "",
    "manifest_description": "SHIPMENT RECEIVED BY JNE COUNTER OFFICER AT [MAKASAR]",
    "manifest_date": "2019-07-30",
    "manifest_time": "20:15",
    "city_name": ""
     },
    {
    "manifest_code": "",
    "manifest_description": "SHIPMENT PICKED UP BY JNE COURIER [MAKASAR]",
    "manifest_date": "2019-07-30",
    "manifest_time": "21:29",
    "city_name": ""
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` to walk through the array elements and pass the sub-array element as call by reference to change its key

```
$jsonToArray = json_decode($json, true);
$oldKey      = 'manifest_description';
$newKey      = 'manifest_description_new';
array_walk($jsonToArray['data']['riwayat'], function(&$v, $k) use ($oldKey,$newKey){
   $oldValue = $v[$oldKey];
   isset($v[$oldKey]) ? ($v[$newKey] = $oldValue) : '';
   unset($v[$oldKey]);
});
```

Live DEMO : https://3v4l.org/CnXSB

Answer (score 0):

You can set the new key and remove the old key like,

```
    $json_array = json_decode($response,true);
    foreach($json_array["riwayat"] as &$item){
        $item["new_key"] = $item["manifest_description"];
        unset($item["manifest_description"]);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_array);
```